# UWP Socket.InputStream.ReadAsync Hangs

Tags: sockets, uwp

I'm having trouble with UWP.  I am trying to bind a StreamSocketListener to act as a small web server but after 20 or so connections the ReadAsync function hangs and the application eventually closes without an error.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private const uint bufferSize = 1024;
private int port = 9000;
public async void Start()
    {
        StreamSocketListener listener = new StreamSocketListener();


        listener.ConnectionReceived += async (sender, args) =>
        {
            string request = null;

            using (IInputStream input = args.Socket.InputStream)
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
                IBuffer buffer = data.AsBuffer();
                uint bytesRead = bufferSize;

                while (bytesRead == bufferSize)
                {
                    IBuffer result = await input.ReadAsync(buffer, bufferSize, InputStreamOptions.Partial);
                    request += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result.ToArray());
                    bytesRead = buffer.Length;
                }

                processRequest(getPath(request), args.Socket.OutputStream);
            }
        };

        await listener.BindServiceNameAsync(port.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better dispose the disused connection in time. When your app receive a new connection, you could release the previous connection in its ConnectionReceived event handler. You could see the official code sample also does the same thing. [SocketActivityStreamSocket/cs/Server](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket/cs/Server/Scenario1_Send.xaml.cs#L43)

Answer (score 0):

I am using similar code (I found it somewhere online) on my Raspberry Pi 3 acting as a simple web server, yeah.. it is very frustrated.  Indeed, I ran into the same issue and I did use "args.Socket.Dispose()" on each request to solve PART OF THE PROBLEM.

I have a windows service client connecting to my Pi simple web server every 30 seconds and my Pi background service just hangs after around 1.5 to 2 hours. After debugging for many hours, I tried to remove the "await" from input.ReadSync, also make sure that your ProcessRequest doesn't do any async/await. It solved my problem, the server becomes stable without hangging. For me it is okay, since I only have one client, so Sync or Async doesn't really matter to me.

One weird problem though... it seems like randomly during the day, the "request" string will receive some garbage instead of the real HTTP request. I still haven't figured out why.   BTW, There is a very good open source project on GitHub called "Catnap.Server", it seems to look pretty powerful. I haven't tried it but if you look at that implementation, they are using Streamreader instead of ReadAsync.

My windows service client has been working perfectly for 3 years when it was connecting to my old version of Raspberry Pi which ran on NOOBS linux, Apache and PHP. It was rock solid stable...  just want to give Win 10 IoT a try and we have to implement our own web server!!???  My experience so far isn't that pleasant honestly.